# Standalone and library?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

Can someone explain to me the meaning and difference of a program that is standalone or library? This code should be altered so it can be run as standalone & library module(??).

I've been trying to split and define functions but I cant figure out how to define a function in this one. Because its a simple formula at this moment.

The code is in Dutch, but I am sure its pretty clear. Body mass Index

Thx for the help

```
import sys

def main():
    count  = 0
    closeprogram  = False
    weight = float(input("Hoeveel weegt u (in kg)?: "))
    height = (float(input("Hoelang bent u (in cm)?: "))/100)
    bmi = round(weight / (height * height))


    while (not klaar and count < 5): #Men kan 5 kéér het BMI berekenen 
        print("\nDit programma berekent uw BMI.")

        if weight < 0 or weight > 150:
            print("ERROR, uw gewicht moet tussen de 0 en 150 kg liggen.")
            continue

        if height <= 0:
            print("ERROR, uw lengte moet hoger dan 0 cm zijn.")
            continue

        else:
            if bmi < 19:
                print("\nUw BMI is",bmi,", dit houdt in dat u ONDER het gemiddelde zit. Vreten!!")
            elif bmi >= 19 and bmi <= 25:
                print("\nUw BMI is",bmi,", u bent HEALTHY!")
            elif bmi > 25 and bmi <= 35:
                print("\nUw BMI is",bmi,", dit houdt in dat u BOVEN het gemiddelde zit. Sporten!!")
            else:
                print("\nERROR, please try again")
            break
        count = count + 1

        if count == 5:
            closeprogram = True
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that it can be imported as a module or executed as a script, usually using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This will be called only when the Python file is invoked as a script.
    main()
```